# Prism INavigationAware invoked on perant view model when navigating in child region

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I experience a weird behavior when trying to navigate to a view in a child region the OnNavigatingFrom and OnNavigatingTo is being invoked on the parent view model

My layout is as follows I have a shell with a content region where I load a view that has a panel region when I want to change the view from the panel region `_regionManager.RequestNavigate("PanelRegion", "ViewB");`  the INavigationAware is being invoked on the content regions view-viewmodel

Comment: Does ViewB have it's own ViewModel? If not, then it is inheriting it's parent ViewModel.

Comment: @BrianLagunas Got it thanks! also for your great library.